# add a TAB specific notification (jquery ui dialog) in chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I a writing an extension with a background.js file that compares the url (every time it changes) with an internal list. If it finds a match, I want to have a popup that shows the user various options.

Currently, as part of my quest to understand extensions, when you visit one of the urls in the list it pops up a Desktop Notification. That is definitely NOT what I want since it is hard to customize and is not specific to the tab.

My ultimate goal is to have something similar to the [jquery ui modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation). I've tried searching, but the similarity to Desktop Notifications makes it difficult. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

after reading more on how to inject JS into a page, I stumbled across a simple way that does not use the content_script paremeter (I don't want to add code to every page and the list of "matching" urls is both long and dynamic). This code can be run from the background.js file (as long as I insert "http://*/" and "https://*/" in permissions inside manifest.json):

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code:"alert('this url matches your list');", runAt:"document_start"});
```

I wrapped that in a function that only gets called AFTER finding out if the url matches one on my (long) list of urls
technically, this answers my question...it would be possible to change that js "code" that I am executing so that it looked a lot nicer and functioned the way I wanted it to...

BUT, that seems like a lot of work, and adding jquery doesn't seem to be an options...anyone have a different method that is simpler?